# How can I create a fragment that loads an objects properties based on the unique id or create a new one? Why is On start called twice?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, bundle, onstart

My current issue that I need help with is the add/edit recipe fragment for my recipe app. I already accomplished adding a freshly new recipe. However, I'm struggling to create the logic that allows for a recipe to be edited inside the same add recipe fragment dynamically. I can see the logs pulling the proper data, but the onStart method runs again creating an issue where the bundle becomes null thus loading a fresh new recipe id preparing the fragment to create a new recipe Vs. editing the recipe that was clicked on. Hopefully, I'm explaining this right.

This is the code in the recipe details that goes to the editrecipefragment that is both the edit/add recipe fragment.

[image]

This is how I receive the keys in the edit recipe fragment.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where `bundle` is initialized and which part of code it can be edited? and why `onStart()` is called twice?

Comment: updated photo. I originally had it initialized in oncreate, but moved it to onstart. Same issues. No difference in results. I don't know why onstart is called twice. That's my question.

Comment: before you call `editRecipe()` what is the currently showing `fragment`?

Comment: recipedetails fragment

Comment: @PavelPoley You can see the progress within the logs

Comment: A little hard to know the project flow with current code parts, are you sure somehow `Activity.onStart()` or `editRecipe()` called twice? or something in `editIngridientAdapter` not triggers recreation of the fragment?

Comment: How best can I show you the full code without exceeding the limit? Thanks for assistance

Comment: private repository in gitHub/bitbacket my email pavelpoley88@gmail.com

Comment: Email sent, thank you.